# Simplify this CAN to CAN transceiver circuit?

Tags: can, digital-isolator

I currently have a circuit that does this, is there a way to simplify this circuit, ossibly with isolation?

Do I need the BJTs? or can I just connect RX to TX and TX to RX then have a CAN to CAN bus isolator?

[image: A sample of a CAN to CAN isolator]

Comment: If you're asking about galvanic isolation between the two circuits then that example clearly doesn't as there are direct connections from one side to the other. If you're asking about something else then hit the [edit] link ...

Comment: This is like a null modem connect with loopback, not isolation.

Comment: I'm rolling back the diagram to the circuit, because the new edit  will  turn the question into a shopping question which is off topic

Comment: What is the result you are trying to achieve? CAN transceivers have built-in loopback since the receiver is looking at CANH/CANL which will be impacted by the state of the TTL Tx line (dependent on dominant/recessive on the bus). I used a part from OnSemi (was an AMI Semi part) years ago that was two transceivers in one IC with some glue logic.

Comment: I'm trying to isolate a CAN bus galvanically. If the other end misbehaves then I don't want any damage to my embedded controller. I've seem that AMI part. https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AMIS-42770-D.PDF

Comment: TI ISO1042? Maxim MAX1488x? NXP TJA1052? ADI ADM305x? And yup, I think that’s the OnSemi part!

Comment: It ain't galvanic isolation if T1 and T2 are regular BJT. The component you are looking for is called "digital isolator", which are more reliable than optocouplers. Alternatively you can get a transceiver with built-in isolation, but then you wed yourself with the manufacturer. While MPC2551 in the standard SO-8 package is relatively cheap and got lots of second source.

Comment: "TI ISO1042? Maxim MAX1488x? NXP TJA1052? ADI ADM305x? And yup, I think that’s the OnSemi part!"

these all convert the CAN bus to RX/TX. I'm looking for a solution that just strait isolates CAN to CAN

Answer (score 2):

The BJT's here seems uneccesary since the CAN bus is designed to be robust and most of the errors would be in missing data frame and not in electrical behaviour. I would connect them together directly to simplify the design and have less components on the board. Although a diode could be a simple solution to avoid reverse current flow.